# How to loop x amount of times based on user input

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying to work on this sample problem that asks a user how many power ball tickets they would like generated, and then it does just that for them..

So far, I have the following:

```
import random

first_five_nums = range(1, 54)  # first five number possibilities
powerball_nums = range(1, 43)  # powerball number possibilities
num_to_select = 5  # to select 5 random numbers for the ticket

five_generated_nums = random.sample(first_five_nums, num_to_select)  # first five numbers
powerball_generated = random.choice(powerball_nums)  # powerball number

print ("Please enter the amount of Powerball tickets you would like to be generated..")
num_tickets = int(raw_input("Number of tickets: "))

for i in num_tickets():
    print ("Your numbers: %s, Powerball: %s") % (five_generated_nums, powerball_generated)
```

When I try to run this, I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\aa_grimes\my_python_works\powerball_generator.py", line 13, in <module>
    for i in num_tickets():
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

I'm somewhat new to python, and haven't had much instruction other than what I've managed to learn on my own, and for that reason, I've completely come to a standstill. I would appreciate anyone's help. Thank you!

Comment: after I tried that, i got: `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable`

Comment: sorry, `for i in range(num_tickets)`, of course

Comment: Try `for i in range(num_tickets)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For iterating up to a value, use the range and xrange functions.

```
for i in range(num_tickets)
```

Comment: after doing this, the code does run, but now when instead of printing x amount of unique tickets numbers and the power ball number, it just prints the same ticket numbers and power ball number x amount of times.

Like so:

`How many tickets would you like generated: 3`

`Your numbers: 1 32 22 34 5   Power ball number: 6`

`Your numbers: 1 32 22 34 5   Power ball number: 6`
`Your numbers: 1 32 22 34 5   Power ball number: 6`

Comment: I found the solution to the above problem.. I just moved the generator variables into the for loop and I now get unique outputs every time.

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Change `for i in num_tickets():` to `for i in xrange(num_tickets):`

`num_tickets` is integer. `xrange(num_tickets)` generates sequence 0, 1, .. `num_tickets - 1`

Comment: Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

```
n=int(input())
for i in range(0,n):
    n=int(input())
```

you can enter n values in this loop and it runs n times.