# I need to loops from 0 to a var [python]

Tags: python

```
CardAmount = input(">?")

while len(dogs) > 0:
    for [im not sure how to only do this for (CardAmount) amount of times]
    playersDeck.append(dogs.pop(0))
    computersDeck.append(dogs.pop(0))
```

dogs is a list with 30 names and 4 attributes on each,
I need the player to be able to choose the amount of cards but for now i have to do all of them, anyone know how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to loop x amount of times based on user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37260065/how-to-loop-x-amount-of-times-based-on-user-input)

Comment: Use the `range` builtin as in `for x in range(CardAmoun):`.

Comment: you should use lower_case_with_underscores for variable names instead of CamelCase : https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(CardAmount):
    # do stuff CardAmount times
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `range()` function. If I understand correctly, your code should be

```
CardAmount = input(">?")

while len(dogs) > 0:
    for i in range(CardAmount):
       playersDeck.append(dogs.pop(0))
       computersDeck.append(dogs.pop(0))
```

For the details [see the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range).

Comment: https://dumptext.com/Vryd7IZS

https://dumptext.com/JpWnb9fG

Not sure why its saying its not defined?

Comment: Probably because the variable is initialized inside the try statement